# responsive menu: how can I make button text but not icon disappear for xs screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm building a site with Bootstrap, and I have  a vertical menu consisting of buttons that have a FontAwesome icon and text. For XS-screens, I don't want the menu to collapse completely, but I want the text to disappear and the button shrink to the size of the icon (which should NOT disappear). How can I get it to do that??

Comment: You need to create a minimal example of your best effort and then post the fiddle OR bootply OR bin. However, please look at the responsive utility classes in the documentation, you can hide the text for xs.

Comment: Like Christina said, use `hidden-xs` on the button text.

Answer (score 1):

This is nice and simple with Bootstrap 3, and has already been mentioned by Christina and cvrebert.

Simply use the `hidden-xs` class with the buttons text as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybrooks321/uufzrjm1/), and the example html below...

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
    <label class="hidden-xs">text</label>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

I have put the button text in a label, but you could just as easily use a div, span, etc.

Oh and I have not bothered using the font awesome glyphs but this will work just as easily with them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
button *:not(i.fa) {
   font-size: 0;
}
```

Now, the `*` selector in CSS is extremely inefficient, so replace that with whatever other elements regularly occur in your button (there aren't a whole lot that are valid in there, so it shouldn't be difficult).  Basically, the CSS is telling your page to render every element that's a child of a button to have a `font-size` of nil - unless it's a FontAwesome icon.

Hope that helps!